# Short proof of the classification of representation-finite symmetric algebras up to stable equivalence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, quivers, stable-category

Assume $K$ is an algebraically closed field and $A$ a finite dimensional $K$-algebra. Assume additionally that $A$ is symmetric and representation-finite.
Then one has the following classification of such algebras up to stable equivalence( source without proof section 3.14 in: Andrzej Skowroński – Selfinjective algebras: finite and tame type):
$A$ is stable equivalent to a

-symmetric Nakayama algebra or

-a trivial extension of a representation finite hereditary algebra or

-a penny-farthing algebra.

Thus for the classification is very nice in the sense that up to stable equivalence all algebras are known explicitly by quiver and relations.
I think this result might be the nicest classification result besides the classification of representation-finite hereditary algebras in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras. So i wonder if there exists a nice elementary proof avoiding many technical things like covering theory. By the way I cant even find a paper with a proof of this result although it might be easy to prove the result after reading the proof of the classification of selfinjective representation-finite algebras, which is very technical and there it seems not possible to write down quiver and relations for every representative explicitly. Note also that the classification up to stable equivalence coincides with the classificaiton up to derived equivalence in this case.

Comment: What is a penny-farthing algebra?

Comment: The appendix of Asashiba's paper [On a lift of an individual stable equivalence to a standard derived equivalence for representation-finite self-injective algebras"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AALGE.0000003543.02426.4d) shows quivers with relations for each representative self-injective algebra of finite representation type (one representative from each stable equivalence class).  The proof of this classification is spread out over several papers of Riedtmann and others, and as far as I know, it has not been compiled in any one place.

Comment: @qiaochu: Those are quiver algebras with a quiver as in figure 3 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.4088.pdf (the first large quiver). I think Gabriel named them like that, see also his book with roiter.